# why python function execution gives me nothing

Tags: python

I'm trying some functions and when running it it gives me nothing

```py
def formatted_city(city_name, country_name):
    formatted_name = city_name + "' " + country_name
    return formatted_name.title()


formatted_city('cairo', 'egypt')
```

[image]

expected : "Cairo' Egypt"

actual result: nothing happens

and when testing it it also gives me nothing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `print` it:

```
print(formatted_city('cairo', 'egypt'))
```

Output:

```
Cairo' Egypt
```

Comment: when testing it it also gives me nothing

Comment: @ahmeddaker What... copy this line and remove the old line, and paste it where the old line was, then run it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the console. If you ran this in google collab (which I did) it will print out the two cities. However in most guis you should not expect anything to print because formatted_name.title() is not saved to any variable. You could do

```
x = formatted_city('cairo', 'egypt') 
print(x)
```

which would print out what you want

Comment: Spyder is one of the environments that would not print anything